# Select dynamic dropdown issue

Tags: selenium, dropdown

I have a problem with the dropdown that developer just upgraded the library AntD 3 to AntD 4. The dropdown list now displays 10 items. If user scrolls down, it will load next 10 items. The current code that I wrote for automation in Java with Selenium does not work. Does anybody help me to fix this case?

Below is the HTML code

```
<div class="ant-select-dropdown ant-select-dropdown-placement-bottomLeft  ant-select-dropdown-hidden" style="min-width: 455px; width: 455px; left: -484px; top: -571px;">
   <div>
      <div role="listbox" id="credential_type_list" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
         <div aria-label="Financial" role="option" id="credential_type_list_1" aria-selected="false">1</div>
         <div aria-label="KPI" role="option" id="credential_type_list_2" aria-selected="false">2</div>
         <div aria-label="Royalty" role="option" id="credential_type_list_3" aria-selected="false">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="rc-virtual-list" style="position: relative;">
         <div class="rc-virtual-list-holder" style="max-height: 256px; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-anchor: none;">
            <div style="height: 448px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
               <div class="rc-virtual-list-holder-inner" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; transform: translateY(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px;">
                  <div aria-selected="true" class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option ant-select-item-option-selected" title="Revenue">
                     <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">Revenue</div>
                     <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div aria-selected="false" class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option" title="Financial">
                     <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">Financial</div>
                     <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div aria-selected="false" class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option ant-select-item-option-active" title="KPI">
                     <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">KPI</div>
                     <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div aria-selected="false" class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option" title="Royalty">
                     <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">Royalty</div>
                     <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div aria-selected="false" class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option" title="Marketing Fund">
                     <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">Marketing Fund</div>
                     <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div aria-selected="false" class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option" title="COGS Adjustments">
                     <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">COGS Adjustments</div>
                     <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div aria-selected="false" class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option" title="Remittance">
                     <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">Remittance</div>
                     <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div aria-selected="false" class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option" title="Payroll">
                     <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">Payroll</div>
                     <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div aria-selected="false" class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option" title="Sales Tax (County)">
                     <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">Sales Tax (County)</div>
                     <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div aria-selected="false" class="ant-select-item ant-select-item-option" title="Sales Tax (State)">
                     <div class="ant-select-item-option-content">Sales Tax (State)</div>
                     <span class="ant-select-item-option-state" unselectable="on" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none;"></span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="rc-virtual-list-scrollbar rc-virtual-list-scrollbar-show" style="width: 8px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; position: absolute; display: none;">
            <div class="rc-virtual-list-scrollbar-thumb" style="width: 100%; height: 128px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); border-radius: 99px; cursor: pointer; user-select: none;"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your code and error here?

Comment: My code is
```
String credType = "//div[@id='credential_type_list']/../div//div[contains(@class, 'select-item-option-content')]";
        List<WebElement> credTypeList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(credType));

        for(WebElement element : credTypeList) {
            if (element.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                element.click();
            }
        }
```